# Remove special character in javascript for a dynamic value

Tags: javascript, dynamic, character-encoding

I have a javascript method

$(document).ready(function() {
                    pageViewed('{!currentName} - Detail Page');

Here currentName can have special characters like a single quote. Is there any way to skip the escape character? while passing it to the pageviewed method?

Is there any method that does this automatically?

Comment: probably wrap the entire {!currentName} in a double quote like var a = "{!currentName}",  if you know a single quote is the only special character that would be coming in. If not use js methods like encodeURI() or encodeURIComponent() to escape the special chars. Now if you want to remove the chars then , we should be able to use regex to remove the chars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from JavaScript, Visualforce has [`functions`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_functions.htm) to escape special characters.

You can use `JSENCODE` as:

```
pageViewed('{!JSENCODE(currentName)} - Detail Page');
```

Additional encoding methods: `HTMLENCODE` or `JSINHTMLENCODE`

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot